# Why is the NebulaGraph tag index not rebuilt?

Tags: nebula-graph

I created a tag index and tried to rebuild it in the Nebula Graph database, but it failed. The log shows `This space is building index.`

I ran `show jobs`, and there were no running jobs.

```
std::vector<AdminSubTask> tasks;
    for (auto it = env_->rebuildIndexGuard_->cbegin();
         it != env_->rebuildIndexGuard_->cend(); ++it) {
        if (std::get<0>(it->first) == space_ && it->second != IndexState::FINISHED) {
            LOG(ERROR) << "This space is building index";
            return cpp2::ErrorCode::E_REBUILD_INDEX_FAILED;
        }
    }
```

The following is the log when the index is not rebuilt.

```
E1226 10:44:49.166803 424281 UpdateNode.h:183] vertex conflict 169:96:171:0dbb49c96ba38d8d49a9cccca0de9e28
E1226 10:44:52.144032 424285 UpdateNode.h:183] vertex conflict 169:13:171:5b09d9d36aa2d8e5d9c5e15d3c1d8245
E1226 10:47:46.856619 265937 Host.cpp:348] [Port: 9780, Space: 128, Part: 233] [Host: 172.23.236.100:9990] Failed to append logs to the host (Err: E_TERM_OUT_OF_DATE)
E1226 10:49:56.923763 424242 RebuildIndexTask.cpp:63] This space is building index
E1226 10:49:56.923795 424242 AdminTaskManager.cpp:254] job 183, genSubTask failed, err=E_REBUILD_INDEX_FAILED
```

And lots of the following errors in the log

`Failed to append logs to the host (Err: E_TERM_OUT_OF_DATE)`

```
E1226 11:19:29.156589 424281 UpdateNode.h:183] vertex conflict 169:21:170:13b689b5cb0c1c415849c250708e4f5e
E1226 11:19:29.284868 424280 UpdateNode.h:183] vertex conflict 169:62:170:2146dc6004a8200ed3c1cca1a7ae7008
E1226 11:19:31.090054 265903 AddVerticesProcessor.cpp:164] The vertex locked : tag 170, vid 3dd7a92570f73d4c8541a6478bbecd65
E1226 11:19:32.039448 424280 UpdateNode.h:183] vertex conflict 169:13:170:1b3b3f5d0387352399feefd670b4c587
E1226 11:19:32.039489 424281 UpdateNode.h:183] vertex conflict 169:13:170:1b3b3f5d0387352399feefd670b4c587
E1226 11:19:32.143121 424282 UpdateNode.h:183] vertex conflict 169:2:170:2290a0580ffec7a1bb30d86dcd366571
```

Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in nebulagraph v2.6, and it was fixed in version 3.x.
I restarted the storage service where the tag index failed to be rebuilt and it worked.